# Thread Exiting With Uncaught Expression

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, uncaught-exception

I have an app that works consist of simple Drawer Navigation with list of menu.
Inside one of the menu, I want to add a page with Tab layout - Swipeable view found on [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) --this app is running without any errors.

I decide to put a button inside one of the menu, which when its pressed will direct the user into the TabLayout's MainActivity.

Now on my Main Project I have two MainActivity classes, the one is MainActivity.java (this is the NavDrawer's) and MainActivity2.java (this is the TabLayout's) and also I manage to copy-pasted all the required files into my Main Project including the adapters.

I put the button in my HomeFragment.java as follows:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately when I click on the button the app crashed showing this logcat

```
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): Process: my.jlm, PID: 1317
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.jlm/my.jlm.MainActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 05:58:52.106: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at my.jlm.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:32)
```

it says the error might caused by MainActivity2.java at line 32 but I don't know what to do with it

this is line 32

```
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

here's my complete MainActivity2

```
public class MainActivity2 extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Initilization
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

// Adding Tabs
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
            .setTabListener(this));
}

/**
 * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
 * */
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // on changing the page
        // make respected tab selected
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }
});
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// on tab selected
// show respected fragment view
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

}
```

Thank you for your kind time.

Comment: Have you tried with `getSupportActionBar();` ? instead of `getActionBar()`

Comment: probably your adapter is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewPager` is `null`. You initialize it like this:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

`findViewById` returns the view if found and `null` otherwise.

> public View findViewById (int id) Added in API level 1
>
> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that
>   was processed in onCreate(Bundle). Returns
>
> ```
> The view if found or null otherwise.
> ```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29).

Your problem is that the view is not found, maybe because it was not created (yet).

Comment: thank you. your post enlighten me, I put the wrong layout for the MainActivity2.java, as it should be the new activity_main2.xml for the "pager" not activity_main.xml (my existing activity layout), which has no pager id inside it.